# Creating a complex custom widget in PyQt5 and adding it to a QGridlayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, customization

I have to create a custom widget that looks like the following:

custom_widget_sketch

[image]

Each custom widget is a representation of one LIPO battery, and displays the battery volatge `(V)`, status text `(charging, discharging, etc)`, serial number of the battery `(S/N)` and three status `LEDs` (yellow, green and red)

After I have created the custom widget I need to add 30 of these in a grid of 6*5. My assumption here is that once I have created that custom widget it should be as simple as adding say a QPushButton in a QGridLayout like so:

```
custom_layput = QGridLayout()
custom_layout.addWidget(custom_widget, 0, 0)
custom_layout.addWidget(custom_widget, 0, 1)

.
.
.

custom_layout.addWidget(custom_widget, 6, 5)
```

The final screen would look like this:

main_window_sketch

[image]

Considering all of these requirements I have the following questions:

1. Will I able able to create such a complex/rich custom widget using PyQt5? Is it doable?
2. Is this the correct approach to create the custom widget: first draw a square using QPainter (this is the blue square in the custom_widget_sketch), then add QLineEdits to dispaly the voltage (V) text, serial number (S/N) text and the Status text, add a QLabel for displaying the "V", "S/N" and "STATUS" labels in the custom widget, then draw the three circles: one each for the yellow, green and red `LEDs`, then use a combination of `QVBoxLayout` and QHBoxLayout to arrange the `QLineEdits`, `QLabels`, the square and the circles (LED indicators)
3. How do I package this custom widget such that I can simply add it to a layout like I would add a `QPushButton` or a `QLineEdit`?

PS: The custom_widget_sketch also contains a line and a square with three lines inside it in the top left corner. This is to depict the connector for the LIPO battery. It may be too complex to implement that right now. So I would be happy even if I am able to implement everything other than these two elements

I have been through a few SO questions but they all refer to one tutorial, which is not my end goal.

I would appreciate any code snippets, general outline of code/steps to follow or links to any articles/tutorials that create custom widgets similar to the one I wish to create.

Comment: You can create a class or ui using qtdesigner for the single widget and add it to a layout multiple times, as you said. For the blinking LEDs you can create QLabels and add red,yellow, green icons to them and use a QTimer to show/hide the icons imitating a blinking led

Comment: Also you can do something with the QPropertyAnimation.  http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qpropertyanimation/

Comment: Hi @Drees, thanks for the suggesstion, I ended up creating a label for each of the LEDs and used `self.yellow_led_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color : yellow; border-color : black; border-width : 1px; border-style : solid; border-radius : 10px; min-height: 20px; min-width: 20px}")` to create a circular label and set colors for the LEDs. I have not implemented the animation yet, but thanks for that link as well.

Answer (score 2):

Python code for the custom widget I ended up creating. The widget looks as follows:

[image: custom_widget_screeenshot]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen,QBrush,QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout,QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QGroupBox
import sys

class BatteryStatusWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BatteryStatusWidget, self).__init__()
        #Voltage widgets
        self.voltage_text = QLineEdit()
        self.voltage_text.setReadOnly(True)
        self.voltage_label = QLabel("V")
        self.voltage_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : white}")

        #Status widgets
        self.status_text = QLineEdit()
        self.status_text.setReadOnly(True)
        self.status_label = QLabel("STATUS")
        self.status_label_font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.status_label_font.setPointSize(12)
        self.status_label.setFont(self.status_label_font)
        self.status_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.status_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : white}")

        #Serial number
        self.serial_number_text = QLineEdit()
        self.serial_number_label = QLabel("S/N")

        #LED widgets
        self.yellow_led_label = QLabel()
        self.yellow_led_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color : yellow; border-color : black; border-width : 1px; border-style : solid; border-radius : 10px; min-height: 20px; min-width: 20px}")
        self.green_led_label = QLabel()
        self.green_led_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color : green; border-color : black; border-width : 1px; border-style : solid; border-radius : 10px; min-height: 20px; min-width: 20px}")
        self.red_led_label = QLabel()
        self.red_led_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color : red; border-color : black; border-width : 1px; border-style : solid; border-radius : 10px; min-height: 20px; min-width: 20px}")

        #Number Identifier Label
        #This label is for tagging the widget with the same label as on the PCB
        self.number_label = QLabel("Test")
        self.number_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.number_label_font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.number_label_font.setPointSize(12)
        self.number_label_font.setBold(True)
        self.number_label.setFont(self.number_label_font)

        #Layouts
        #voltage layout
        self.voltage_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.voltage_layout.addWidget(self.voltage_text)
        self.voltage_layout.addWidget(self.voltage_label)

        #Serial number layout
        self.serial_num_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.serial_num_layout.addWidget(self.serial_number_label)
        self.serial_num_layout.addWidget(self.serial_number_text)

        #Voltage and status box layouts
        self.blue_container = QWidget()
        self.blue_container.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(77, 122, 194);")
        self.blue_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.blue_box_layout.addLayout(self.voltage_layout)
        self.blue_box_layout.addWidget(self.status_text)
        self.blue_box_layout.addWidget(self.status_label)
        self.blue_container.setLayout(self.blue_box_layout)


        #Blue box+ serial num layout
        self.non_led_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        #self.non_led_layout.addWidget(self.number_label)
        self.non_led_layout.addWidget(self.blue_container)
        self.non_led_layout.addLayout(self.serial_num_layout)

        #LED layout
        self.led_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.led_layout.addWidget(self.yellow_led_label)
        self.led_layout.addWidget(self.green_led_label)
        self.led_layout.addWidget(self.red_led_label)
        self.led_layout.addStretch(1)

        #Main Layout
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.non_led_layout)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.led_layout)

        #Main group box
        self.main_group_box = QGroupBox()
        self.main_group_box.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{font-size: 10px}")
        self.main_group_box.setTitle("Chan #")
        self.main_group_box.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        #Outer main layout to accomodate the group box
        self.outer_main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.outer_main_layout.addWidget(self.main_group_box)

        #Set the main layout
        self.setLayout(self.outer_main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Battery Widget")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = BatteryStatusWidget()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I was able to easily create 30 instances of the custom widget and add it to a `QGridLayout` as I posted in my question. The final GUI screen looks as follows:

[image: final_GUI_window_screenshot]

Comment: Please I need this code to fix a problem of mine

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use QPainter for the blue square, as you can use stylesheets for your whole widget, the trick is to use selectors.

I tried to create your widget and used this stylesheet:

```
    Battery {
        background-color: white;
    }
    QFrame#statusFrame {
        background-color: rgb(64, 112, 190);
    }
    QFrame#statusFrame QLabel {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 24pt;
    }
    QLineEdit {
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 24pt;
    }
    #serialLabel {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16pt;
    }
```

I created a "container" QWidget, the status rectangle is actually a QFrame with its own layout, which I named `statusFrame` (you can set it in designer, or by means of `setObjectName(str)`).
By using object names and child selectors, I was able to set specific fonts for its labels by using the `QFrame#statusFrame QLabel` selector (which means "apply to each QLabel that is a child of a QFrame"); I also set the `serialLabel` object name to the s/n label, allowing me to set a different font size.

You can do this from code or using designer, just remember to set the right object names and parent/children hierarchy.

I was able to draw the "connector" part too, which requires to set fixed margins to the main widget:

```py
class Battery(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    connPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    connPath.addRect(30, 10, 40, 28)
    connPath.moveTo(30, 16)
    connPath.lineTo(45, 16)
    connPath.moveTo(30, 24)
    connPath.lineTo(45, 24)
    connPath.moveTo(30, 32)
    connPath.lineTo(45, 32)
    cablePen = QtGui.QColor(77, 122, 194)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        # the following is only if you create the whole widget from code,
        # otherwise ensure to set both widget and layout contentsMargins
        # accordingly in designer
        self.setContentsMargins(25, 50, 10, 10)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # ...

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.translate(.5, .5)
        qp.drawPath(self.connPath)

        qp.setPen(self.cablePen)
        cablePath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        cablePath.moveTo(30, 24)
        top = self.statusFrame.geometry().top()
        cablePath.quadTo(0, top + 20, 25, top + 40)
        qp.drawPath(cablePath)
```

As you can see, it's almost the same as yours.

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code snippet to draw the connector. We ended up excluding it due to space considerations. I ended up creating a vertical layout for the blue box, added it to a container widget and set the color on the widget to blue using `setStyleSheet`.
I did this because I have not used `QFrame` before. Is there a specific reason why you prefer `QFrame` over Layout in this case? Or was it becuase you wanted to substitute it for the QPainter approach I had posted in the original question?

Comment: I am also curious as to how you arrived at the `cablePen = QtGui.QColor(77, 122, 194)` RBG numbering for the blue? I ended up using that, but would like to find out for future references.

Comment: The QFrame was indeed to avoid unnecessary paintEvent override, since only widgets can be used as stylesheet element selectors, not layouts; it could also done by means of a simple QWidget, as long as a correct selector (object name or custom property) is used. I used your source image to get the cable color with a color picker (actually, Qt's pixeltool); since it's antialised I just choose the color that matched your example the most.