# How to add Lables at Tick Position in Slider in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qslider

At Every Position of Tick should be labeled

For Example:

I have slider and want to display time as tick label which should be customization as per video time length.

[image: In this Image want to label the slider Tick]

As Like This Image I want to Label Time in format '10.55.AM'.

Comment: You can always subclass with custom `paintEvent`

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota Can you share some Reference code or Content??

Comment: @MilanSoliya Have a look at these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768266/painting-in-a-qlabel-with-paintevent) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299933/creating-a-complex-custom-widget-in-pyqt5-and-adding-it-to-a-qgridlayout); basically, you reimplement the [`paintEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) method, call the base implementation and then draw over it. The only problem is that painting text *over* an already painted QSlider might result in superimposed text. If you have issues with that, create a new question or better edit this one.